# How to stop marquee when click and then display the whole text?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have following html marguee code on my wordpress

`<marquee>Runing Text....</marquee>`

I have a question, how to stop marquee when mouse click on that marquee then display the whole marquee text centerly?

I'm not familiar with css code and html code.

Comment: Welcome, please read the section https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code any answer will be just a guess. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As marquee is deprecated you may want to look at alternative approaches using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you looking for?  or you mean, after click then the marquee will hide and show the original context?

```js
   var divMarq = document.getElementById("showAllmarquee");
   var mar = document.querySelector("marquee");
   
    function openDiv() {
      mar.stop();
      divMarq.innerText = mar.innerText;
      divMarq.style.display = "block";
      mar.style.display = "none";
    }

    function closeDiv() {
      mar.start();
      divMarq.innerText = '';
      divMarq.style.display = "none";
      mar.style.display = "block";
    }
```

```css
#showAllmarquee{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onclick="openDiv();">
Go on... toggle me to start and to stop!
</marquee>
<div id="showAllmarquee" onclick="closeDiv();"></div>
```

Comment: Yes correct, marquee stop when click and show all context centerly, but still show on that marquee line/banner...not new line.

Comment: I updated my post. see for your reference